# How to convert a VS 2008 solution to VS 2010 without changing targeted .net version?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

When opening a Visual Studio 2008 solution in Visual Studio 2010 - VS converts it to a VS 2010 solution. Unfortunately, it also changes the targeted .net version from 3.5 to 4.0.

How can I avoid that? (**Not**: How to undo that?)

Comment: You may find this helpful http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2009/10/12/targeting-earlier-net-frameworks-2-0-3-0-3-5-using-visual-studio-2010-beta2.aspx

Comment: That's the point of an IDE, it takes care of 95% of the obscure details of building a program.  Helping you to get them right without having to pay attention to it.  Being stuck on a 7 year old version of free software strongly fits the "not getting it right" category.

Comment: @HansPassant "That's the point of an IDE" - Exactly. Instead of converting a solution targeting 4.0 to 3.5 and then manually changing everything that VS failed to - I rather let VS _create_ a solution targeting 3.5 - for which I need VS 2008. The point about the free version is well taken.

Answer (score 2):

You can't avoid it - the migration tool automatically changes the framework version.  The only option is to undo it by changing back after the fact.

Comment: Thanks. I assume it also changes other references in the solution and I have to track them all down. Right? (That's actually what I'm trying to avoid, in order to avoid any mistakes.)

Comment: @ispiro: My solution to "avoid any mistakes": Use source control, and do a line by line review of the diff before committing it to the central source control server.

Comment: @ispiro You just have to change the framework version in the project properties for every project.  Checking the source control change logs prior to commit is a great idea, though.